# Adding a fragment and calling .replace() causing a memory leak in the added fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, leakcanary

I have a BottomNavigationView with 3 tabs. On every tab click, it calls `.replace()`

````
private void initBottomNavigation() {

        mBottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuItem -> {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.bottomnav_admin_home:                <---- Tab 1
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(
                                        R.id.admin_fragment_container,
                                        new AdminHomeFragment(),
                                        Constants.FRAGMENT_ADMIN_HOME
                                )
                                .commit();
                    }

                    ...Tab two
                    ....Tab three

                    return true;
    ```
````

In my 3rd tab, I have a button that adds a fragment on top of the fragment container:

[image]

When I click on the button, it calls this to add another Fragment ontop of the fragment container:

```
getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(
                        R.id.admin_fragment_container,
                        new DeactivateUserFragment(),
                        Constants.FRAGMENT_ADMIN_DEACTIVATE_USER
                )
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .commit();
```

When I am on the **added** Fragment, I click on the second tab which calls `.replace()`, it causes a memory leak in my **added** Fragment.

I've reduced down all the code in the added Fragment, but I can't figure out why it's still leaking.

Entire Code for added fragment:

```
public class DeactivateUserFragment extends Fragment{
    private static final String TAG = "FragmentDeactivatedUser";

    @BindView(R.id.recycler_view) RecyclerView mRecycler;

    @BindView(R.id.parent_layout) ViewGroup mParentLayout;

    @BindView(R.id.progress_bar) ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private Context                mContext;
    private SimpleListUsersAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<UserInfo>    mList = new ArrayList<>();
    private DeactivateViewModel    mViewModel;
    private AuthStateManager mAuthStateManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = getContext();

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin_deactivate_user, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);



        return view;
    }

    
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_back)
    public void onBackBtnClick(){
        getParentFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }


}
```

The leak:

```
androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.example.
​     testproject.ui.admin.deactivate.DeactivateUserFragment received
​     Fragment#onDestroyView() callback (references to its views should be
​     cleared to prevent leaks))
​     Retaining 106.7 kB in 1469 objects
​     key = e50280e9-58bd-4ecd-bc1b-a2d6cc188639
​     watchDurationMillis = 108539
​     retainedDurationMillis = 103532
​     View not part of a window view hierarchy
​     View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
​     View.mID = R.id.parent_layout
​     View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
​     mContext instance of com.example.testproject.ui.admin.AdminActivity
​     with mDestroyed = false
```

**Edit 1:________________________________**

Why does removing these three lines no longer cause a memory leak?

```
@BindView(R.id.recycler_view) RecyclerView mRecycler;

    @BindView(R.id.parent_layout) ViewGroup mParentLayout;

    @BindView(R.id.progress_bar) ProgressBar mProgressBar;
```

I am not using the variables in any of the code, just having them binded.
I am extremely confused how this is causes the leak

**Edit 2: __________________________________**

I've tried setting the views to null in `onDestroyView()` and unbinding Butterknife but still leaks.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/585

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyView: Called");
        unbinder.unbind();
        mRecycler = null;
        mParentLayout = null;
        mProgressBar = null;
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

I've tried removing the views one by one... progress bar, recycler, and mParentLayout. Only until I remove all 3, does it not leak anymore

I removed Butterknife from the fragment and only use findViewById but still has same issue

Comment: can you set these views to `null` in `onDestroy()` of their fragment and see

Comment: ```onDestroy()``` isn't being called so I put them in ```onDestroyView()```. I've also tried calling unbind butterknife but it's still leaking

Comment: this also happens when you create an empty fragment so it's not a matter of setting the variables null

Comment: if you used Android profiler and you switch between the fragments the memory leak detecter only on the fragments which are not attached
for example if you are on fragment A and you switch to fragment B and when you come back to fragment A the android profiler says that fragment B is leak

Comment: Try to using viewbinding and the third-party https://github.com/wada811/ViewBinding-ktx . It doesn't keep a strong reference to the fragment's view. also it doesn't need to set null for views

Comment: Can you add all code of `DeactivateUserFragment` which is causing leak after Edit3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was setting a global variable for the butterknife's `Binder` in my Fragment and calling `Unbind` in the `onDestroyView()`

```
private Unbinder unbinder;
```

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin_link_family, container, false);
        
        return view;
    }
```

I also had my adapter binded

`private SimpleListUsersAdapter adapter;`

```
Inside Adapter class


 class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.action_type)
        TextView userAction;
        @BindView(R.id.date)
        TextView date;
        @BindView(R.id.amount)
        TextView amount;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
```

So I needed to set the adapter to null also in `onDestroyView`

```
Fragment Class

@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        adapter = null;
        unbinder.unbind();
}
```

Needed to do both to stop leak

Answer (score -1):

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin_deactivate_user, container, false);
        unbinder=ButterKnife.bind(this, view);//initialise the unbinder here


      return view;
    }

    Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyView: Called");
  
    if(unbinder!=null){
        unbinder.unbind();
        unbinder = null;
    }
   
    super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

Try adding this in your recycler adapter code:

```
     @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
       super.onDestroyView();
     }
```

Comment: Did you read the edits? I've already tried unbinding and removing butterknife and using ```findViewById``` instead but it still happens

Comment: try setting the value of unbinder to null after unbinding it in ondestroyview

Comment: I already said Butterknife isn't the issue

Comment: Your problem might be related to recycler view.

Comment: I think you havent cleared the adapter in your recycler view adapter code.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to remove every reference initialized in `onCreate` or `onCreateView` respectively in your `onDestroy` and `onDestroyView`.
So if you have :

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = getContext();

    }
```

You should also have :

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mContext = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

I recommend you to not store the context in attributes as you have access to the method `getContext()` everywhere in an android `Fragment` subclass.

Context are a habitual source of leak.

I don't know what exactly are the types of your others attributes but you should keep the same philosophy.